# Sending requests using Sockets through a SOCKS5 Proxy Server in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix, socks

I have a simple networking program for sending and responding to HTTP requests/responses. However, if I wanted to send a HTTP or another request via a SOCKS5 proxy, how would I go about this? I'm using C Unix sockets.

I could solve this by creating a proxy server in Linux. However, my intention is so that I can send this to a proxy server I do not own so that it can be forwarded to the destination server. I couldn't seem to find a library. I found an RFC for it which I've read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt , but i'm still not 100% unsure how to format my request.

Am I supposed to send the segments for the handshakes as hex? If so, would I send a string of hex `0F3504` or `\x0F \x35 \x04` or `0x0F3504`? Another question is do i need to denote that header = value in the message, or does the SOCKS5 server know what header i am referring to by the position of the byte it is looking at from the message I've sent?

Any clear up would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote an open source C library that may help you: https://github.com/brechtsanders/proxysocket

Maybe you can use the library. Its quite easy, just replace the `connect()` with stuff from the library and for the rest you can keep the rest of your code that uses the socket that is returned.

Or you can take a peek in the code to see how it's done there.